# jquery not getting values from dynamic input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have setup a hidden input field in **Laravel 5.7** view  as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sbj_type_id" value="{{ $admin_option->last_sbj_type_id == $subject->id ? 'selected' : '' }}">
```

And I'm trying to get the value of this field in jquery as:

```
$('input[name^="sbj_type_id"]').each(function() { alert($(this).val()); });
```

but empty alert is coming, after that I tried `{{ dd($admin_option->last_sbj_type_id }}`, then value displayed, but not getting it in jquery, first it was working with simple code as:

```
var sbj_type_id = $('input[name="sbj_type_id"]').val();
```

Today it's not working at all.

Comment: Maybe the line you alert the value is executed before the actual value is assigned.

Comment: I also moved current line to the end of file not working at all

Comment: Hardcode the value of the input field and try, may be the ternary condition logic is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Jquery code is working so...

In your ternary operator, if the condition is false you return an empty string.
Try to return something like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="sbj_type_id" value="{{ $admin_option->last_sbj_type_id == $subject->id ? 'selected' : 'false' }}">
```

You will see where the problem is coming from.